# Use Chrome device inspector with or without chrome 39.0.2171.59 +

Tags: google-chrome, android, google-chrome-devtools

I used to be able to inspect devices with Chrome Canary ? Since today.

### Device inspector prompt that should install **Chrome 39.0.2171xx**:

The two suggested versions number are exactly the chrome mobile versions I have installed on the two respective devices I try to test with.

[image]

### Canary says it's up to date at version 38.0.2120.0

[image]

### So What should I do to be able to use Chrome device inspector again ?

xx

Answer (score 0):

You can't use device inspector with an older version of chrome on your desktop than on the device. In my case Chrome auto update was not functioning. I had to update manually.

I just went to Canary Download page

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html

[image]

and Chrome beta Download page

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html

[image]

### Now I can enjoy Chrome's latest features

http://blog.chromium.org/2015/01/chrome-41-beta-new-es6-features-and.html